# apscheduler.add_job how can I use the trigger parameter?

Tags: python-3.x, apscheduler

I'm using [apscheduler](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io) .

I don't really understand the ['add_job'](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.add_job) method .

This works fine :

```
job = scheduler.add_job( my_housekeeping_function,
                        'interval',
                        kwargs={'config':config},
                        seconds=60,
                        )
```

but I don't understand how the argument 'interval' (which I'm using succesfully) matches what is shown in the documentation : https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.add_job .

It does seem that the second argument can be a 'str' (although as far as I can tell there's no indication of what are valid values), however there's indication that I can include a keyword argument of 'seconds' but when I do it all works .

Can anyone explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you look for the documentation? In the official API documentation, the valid values are listed right in the [description of add_job()](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.add_job). The same list can also be found in the [User Guide](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#choosing-the-right-scheduler-job-store-s-executor-s-and-trigger-s).

What's happening here is that APScheduler looks up the corresponding setuptools entry point from the `apscheduler.triggers` namespace. The canonical list of built-in triggers can be found in [setup.py](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/master/setup.py#L68-L73).

Comment: OK thanks. I had read the add_job doco but because I skipped down to the parameter list I missed the reference to the trigger alias. I guess the key thing is what you linked to in the setup.py. Whatever is going on there is beyond my experience of Python, I'll have to read up on it, but in essence when you use the string 'interval' in the 'add_job' arguments it's getting mapped to apscheduler.triggers.interval:IntervalTrigger' ? Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.